# Understanding the meaning of this c++ line

Tags: c++, hex, preprocessor-directive

What is the purpose of 0xFF?

```
#define INFINITY2        0xff
```

I need your help to understand how this line works.

What does the `0xff` do?

Comment: Did you try to search on anything else before here ?

Answer (score 2):

`0xff` is the hex representation of `255`. They are just defining some macro/constant named `INFINITY2` that has a value of `255`.